# Ajax not firing in div populated by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a div which is populated via an ajax request.
Within the div is a form which when completed should use the same type of ajax request to populate a further div. I have used the same method to create both but the second javascript does not run:

First one (which works):

```
<div class="content_text" id="searchbysurname">
          <p><form name="searchbysurname">  
            <b>Search by Surname: </b><input class="inline" type="text" name="q">
            <input type="submit"></form>
             <script>
     $('#searchbysurname form').submit(function(){
          var data=$(this).serialize();
          // post data
          $.post('searchbysurname_test.php', data , function(returnData){
                      $('#resultstable').html( returnData)
          })

          return false; // stops browser from doing default submit process
    });
      </script>
            <div id="resultstable"></div>
```

Second one (which is in the resultstable div) that doesnt work:

```
<? require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController(); 

$q = ($_POST['q']);
$employees=array();
$sql = "SELECT employees.employeeid, employees.firstname, employees.surname FROM employees  where UCASE(employees.surname) LIKE UCASE('%".$q."%')";
$employees = $db_handle->runQuery($sql); ?>
<table class="invisible">
<?
          if(isset($employees) && !empty($employees)){
          foreach($employees as $k=>$v) {
         ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $employees[$k]["firstname"]; ?>  <?php echo $employees[$k]["surname"]; ?> </td>
    <td><div id="viewemployeedetails<? echo $employees[$k]["employeeid"]?>">
        <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $employees[$k]["employeeid"]?>">
            <input type="submit" value="View">
        </form>
     </div></td>

      <div id="mainpart"><b></b></div>
            <script>
     $('viewemployeedetails<? echo $employees[$k]["employeeid"]?> form').submit(function(){
          var data=$(this).serialize();
          // post data
          $.post('viewemployeedetails.php', data , function(returnData){
                      $('#mainpart').html( returnData)
          })

          return false; // stops browser from doing default submit process
    });
      </script>
```

Comment: You are missing a **#** in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not related to your question but you shouldn't be using the PHP short tag notation, it has been deprecated: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Your first block of code is HTML with inline Javascript, which is an awful way to do things, you will get hard to debug errors if you insist on using Javascript in this way. You should be putting your Javascript in a separate file from the HTML and including it just before the final body tag. Ideally you should be using window.onload (or other similar methods, like a closure or jQuery's .ready() method) to ensure that DOM traversing elements of your script are only parsed after the DOM is fully loaded.

Your second block of Javascript code will never run because it doesn't exist when the browser parses the HTML. It's only injected later but Javascript doesn't work that way. You *can* inject javascript dynamically but not like that. You would have to do something like this:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://www.somedomain.com/somescript.js';
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

I took this code from here: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

Comment: So would I put the var headid etc at the top of the second section? I ended up putting the JavaScript where I did as originally it wasn't working as it was trying to bind to an element that wasn't created yet.

Comment: No, you will have to strip your second section's javascript out, put it in it's own file, then add the snippet to your first section just after you pull in the dynamic content. I.e. after $('#resultstable').html( returnData )